# Composer edited and added a new line to my Laravels index.php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Composer edited and added a new line to my index.php file in laravel project.

include 'vendor/composer/autoload_script.php';

Because of that line my whole project stopped working. it added a js script file

to every response.
it caused so much problems especially with json responses.

I removed the line manually but it again appeared next day

how can i avoid this problem in future.

Comment: Try `include 'vendor/autoload.php';` instead :/

Comment: include 'vendor/composer/autoload_script.php'; this line is not included by me ..it has been automatically added everyday. i removed it but it reappears the next day

Comment: what you have installed last? any plugin or anything?

Comment: nothing. The application is in production and it was happened in live server.

Comment: How do you know it was composer? Composer should only run if you (or someone) tells it to run. Do you have any cron jobs?

Comment: yeah the main cron job for Laravel scheduler.

Comment: You were likely hacked somehow. The JS file is probably a crypto miner script from coinhive or something else malicious.